# TAGS: reports and joined-reports

Tags: discussion, tag-merge, tagging

To merge or not? and if not - than we need to change the reports wiki.

[reports](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reports) - notes that the format can be joined as well.

[joined-reports](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joined-reports) - is it redundant?

thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

I would vote for leaving them separate - '[Joined Reports](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/reports_joined_format_overview.htm)' is a distinct Salesforce feature delivered in Spring '12, so in many people's minds they are a separate animal.

Comment: that's fine with me, so do you think we need to edit the reports tag wiki?

Comment: Sure - is that you volunteering? ;-)

Comment: I agree (once again). Reports is a general tag, which shouldn't imply there can be no need for more specific tags. To me this is not different from apex & batch-apex.